# Adeept Arduino Mega 2560 isn't recognized

Tags: arduino-mega, hardware

So recently, I purchased an Arduino Mega 2560 Kit from Amazon, which was customized from this company called Adeept. But when I tried to plug it into my computer, it didn't recognize it. This means my device manager didn't change in any way, shape, or form. The Arduino IDE that I fully downloaded couldn't upload code, and I also tried using different USB cords, and I tried using another computer as well, but it still didn't work.

**Is there a driver that I need to upload or something else that I'm missing?**

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: ask Adeept ... BTW, if windows does not detect it, then trying Arduino IDE is an exercise in futility